# Boost BCCL Container Algorithm Working Example

Tags: c++, algorithm, boost, containers, c++-concepts

Could someone *please* give a *complete* (including all header files) *working* (that compiles) example of how to use Boost BCCL on a for example a `boost::RandomAccessContainer` together with std::sort?

Answer (score 3):

What’s wrong with the example given in the documentation?

Granted, it’s not complete but it should be trivial to get it to compile …

Furthermore, Your request cannot be fulfilled: you want concept checking for `std::sort`, but this function cannot be re-defined. You could of course define your own sorting function, and use the BCCL code provided by the documentation:

```
#include <algorithm>

#include "boost/concept/requires.hpp"

template<typename I>
BOOST_CONCEPT_REQUIRES(
    ((Mutable_RandomAccessIterator<I>))
    ((LessThanComparable<typename Mutable_RandomAccessIterator<I>::value_type>)),
    (void)) // return type
    sort(I begin, I end)
{
    std::sort(begin, end);
}

int main() {
    int a[] = { 1, 4, 3, 2, 6, 5 };
    sort(a, a + 6);
}
```

**Note**: I have *never* used the BCCL. Hacking the above together was trivial and took me less than five minutes. Certainly you could have done the same?

Comment: That doesn't compile on my Ubuntu 11.04 using GCC 4.6.1: